# Extjs Model used by 2 Stores

Tags: extjs

I work with two stores: 
- serverStore has ajax proxy to read data from server;
- localStore has localstore proxy to work with data on client.
These 2 stores use the same data model. And it works fine for reading data from server and putting it on local machine browser and rendering to the grid.
Now Im facing with updating records to local store and it turned out that I need to create new model instance for retrieved records in order to update them. But I get the next exception:
Uncaught Ext.data.proxy.Server.buildUrl(): You are using a ServerProxy but have not supplied it with a url. 
How can I work with local store in this situation? What is the right application design for this?

Comment: Which Ext versions? Can you post a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com) so that we can run it?

Comment: 4.2.1,  fiddle will take some time cuase I ll have to mock server data(Im workin with localhost). Is there any way to cast models?

Comment: You only need JSON to simulate the server-side.

Comment: Can you give a necessary code from your spesific problem ?